# When uploading a video in PHP to a server, why do I get video/3gpp even though the video is video/mp4?

Tags: php, file-upload, mp4

when I uploading a video/mp4 video in PHP, it has to check it out using

```
$mimeFinfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($mimeFinfo, $\_FILES\['video'\]\["tmp_name"\]); 
finfo_close($mimeFinfo);
$mime_type = strtolower($mime_type);
```

But inside the program, other things like `pathinfo($\_FILES\['video'\]\['name'\],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` have been detected as mp4 files, while the above finfo extension has been detected as `video/3gpp`. Why does that happen?

> This $mime_type has been detected as a video/3gpp instead of video/mp4 as it is? Why is that?  Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Is the escaping part of real code or for formatting here?

Comment: Its part of the whole code but $mime_type should be video/mp4 instead of video/3gpp. And that variable only prevents the video to upload due that replacement.

Comment: Mime type and container/extension aren't the same. Are you sure it is not 3gp?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GP_and_3G2 says "Some cell phones use the .mp4 extension for 3GP video" and "The 3GP file format stores video streams as MPEG-4 Part 2, H.263, or MPEG-4 Part 10 (AVC/H.264)".

Comment: @ceejayoz The finfo echo out video/3gpp, So it can be right?

Comment: @user3783243 I'm sure, its no video/3gp its video/3gpp.

Comment: @Mikejohn They're the same thing. First line on that Wikipedia article: `3GP (3GPP file format)`